# Reference the database from a stored proc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this T-SQL to get index stats (edited for brevity):

```
SET @db_id = DB_ID(N'TestDB');
SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'TestDB.dbo.Users');
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(@db_id, @object_id, NULL, NULL , 'LIMITED');
```

I want to be able to encapsulate this into a stored proc and call it for whichever database the stored proc is in, but the DB name is hard-coded, how can I get the database name dynamically?

Does T-SQL have anything like:

> SET @db_id = DB_ID(this);

Comment: Have a look at [db_name()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `db_id()` is called with no parameter it returns the id of the current database  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx

so you could just use:
`set @db_id=db_id()`

And having read the rest of the question, you could call `object_id()` without the db name. If the object exists you'll get the id, if not `NULL`. So:
`SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users');`

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking I'll pass the name into the sproc and have an option to run for all tables.